# Matching more than one word in cell, instead of matching always one word

Tags: python

I created a class with a dictionary where

- the first key is a string of words,
- the second is a category which has to be given in column "Category", and
- the third is something like a counter which determines how many words from the first key have to be detected in every cell in column "NameOfProduct".

You can see the example below in the code.

The problem is that when it matches only 1 word of a cell, it accepts the category immediately, but it has to find 1, 2 or 3 words (depending on 3rd key - `dict.count`) before giving this category.

How can I make the code search for every word in `dict.productName` instead of only one word?

This is the table structure:

| 0 | Partnumber | NameOfProduct | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000001 | GV2ME MOTOR CB THERM/MAG 4-6.3A AP |  |
| 2 | 1000002 | GV2ME MOTOR CB THERM/MAG 17-23A AP |  |
| 3 | 1000003 | BELL TRANSFORMER 16VA 230VCA 8..12VCA |  |
| 4 | 1000004 | CANALIS LENGTH KBA40 WHITE |  |
| 5 | 1000005 | 4 CONNECTORS (6X 1.5-35MMІ) PH BARRIERS |  |
| 6 | 1000006 | 3 RIGHT ANGLE TERMINAL EXT PH BARRIERS |  |
| 7 | 1000007 | ROT HANDLE KEYLOCK ADAPTER W O KEYLOCK |  |
| 8 | 1000008 | MN 60V DC UNDERVOLTAGE RELEASE |  |
| 9 | 1000009 | INSULATION MONITORING MODULE 3P TNS TT NSX100 250 CIRCUIT BREAKER ACCESSORY |  |
| 10 | 1000010 | Vigi 440V-550V 3P for NSX100/160 |  |
| 11 | 1000011 | VIGICOMPACT PLUG IN KIT 3P |  |
| 12 | 1000012 | MN 48V DC UNDERVOLTAGE |  |

**You can copy/paste table structure from here:**

```
0   Partnumber  NameOfProduct   Category
1   1000001 GV2ME MOTOR CB THERM/MAG 4-6.3A AP  
2   1000002 GV2ME MOTOR CB THERM/MAG 17-23A AP  
3   1000003 BELL TRANSFORMER 16VA 230VCA 8..12VCA   
4   1000004 CANALIS LENGTH KBA40 WHITE  
5   1000005 4 CONNECTORS (6X 1.5-35MMІ) PH BARRIERS 
6   1000006 3 RIGHT ANGLE TERMINAL EXT PH BARRIERS  
7   1000007 ROT HANDLE KEYLOCK ADAPTER W O KEYLOCK  
8   1000008 MN 60V DC UNDERVOLTAGE RELEASE  
9   1000009 INSULATION MONITORING MODULE 3P TNS TT  NSX100 250 CIRCUIT BREAKER ACCESSORY    
10  1000010 Vigi 440V-550V 3P for NSX100/160    
11  1000011 VIGICOMPACT PLUG IN KIT 3P  
12  1000012 MN 48V DC UNDERVOLTAGE
```

**This is the code:**

```py
import openpyxl


# Product class for easy products management
class Product:
    def __init__(self, productName, category, count):
        self.productName = productName
        self.category = category
        self.count = count


inv_file = openpyxl.load_workbook("web_import_view.xlsx")
product_list = inv_file["Sheet1"]

dicts = [
    # [0] - key words for searching in name of product
    # [1] - category name
    # [2] - how many words have to be found, to be given category from [1]

    Product(["gv2me", "motor"], "Motor breakers", 2),
    Product(["undervoltage", "release"], "Undervoltage", 2),
    Product(["vigicompact", "plug", "kit"], "Vigicompact", 3)
]

for product_row in range(2, product_list.max_row + 1):
    # column C (3), NameOfProduct
    name_of_product = product_list.cell(product_row, 3).value
    # column D (4), Category
    category_of_product = product_list.cell(product_row, 4)
    divided_words = name_of_product.split()

    for dict in dicts:
        counter = 0
        for w in divided_words:
            for z in dict.productName:
                # word_name = w.lower()
                # word_dict = z.lower()
                while w.lower() in z.lower():
                    if w.lower() == z.lower():
                        counter += 1
                        # print(f'Matched word is {w.lower()} from {name_of_product}')
                        if counter == dict.count:
                            print(f'Found {dict.count} matches in {name_of_product}')
                            # print(f'The name of product is {name_of_product}')
                            category_of_product.value = dict.category
                            counter = 0
                            break
                    else:
                        break

inv_file.save("web_import_view.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your code is this part:

```py
while w.lower() in z.lower():
    if w.lower() == z.lower():
        # ...
    else:
        break
```

The `while` causes the comparison to be repeated. So the inner `if` statement is executed either 0 times or an infinite amount of times. This cause your counter to be incremented until the required amount, at which point it considers the product to "match" and `break` out of the loop.

The code could be fixed pretty easily by removing the `while` loop.

However, I have some other suggestions as well:

- Don't use `dict` as a variable name, since it is a built-in time. You might get unexpected results if you're getting used to doing this.
- Pay some attention to proper naming. This makes your code easier to understand. You're now using the term "product" for both the rows in the Excel sheet as well the class and the variables that define the categories. You could name the class 'Category' instead, to avoid the confusion.
- If you always want to match all words in the list (you're current example seems to suggest so), than it's not necessary to specify the `count` variable. This could be easily derived from the length of the word list.
- Since the words that define your categories are already lowercase, you don't have to use `.lower()` in every comparison.

My modified code, which does what I think you want, is like this:

```py
import openpyxl

class Category:
    def __init__(self, name, words, required_count=None):
        self.name = name  # name of the category
        self.words = words  # words to be detected
        self.required_count = required_count or len(words)


CATEGORIES = [
    Category('Motor breakers', ['gv2me', 'motor']),
    Category('Undervoltage', ['undervoltage', 'release']),
    # Category('Vigicompact', ['vigicompact', 'plug', 'kit']),
    # Just for demonstration purposes, this should also work:
    Category('Vigicompact', ['vigicompact', 'plug', 'kit', 'foo', 'bar', 'qux'], 3),  # at least 3 of these words
]


def update_categories(path):
    inv_file = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
    product_list = inv_file['Sheet1']

    for product_row in range(2, product_list.max_row + 1):
        # column C (3), NameOfProduct
        product_name = product_list.cell(product_row, 3).value
        # NOTE: I'm converting all words to lowercase here instead of in the loop below
        product_name_words = [word.lower() for word in product_name.split()]
        # column D (4), Category
        product_category = product_list.cell(product_row, 4)
        # clear value
        product_category.value = ''

        for category in CATEGORIES:
            count = sum(word in product_name_words for word in category.words)
            print('Found %d/%d matches in %s.' % (count, len(category.words), product_name))
            if count >= category.required_count:
                print(f'The name of product is {product_name}')
                product_category.value = category.name
                break

    inv_file.save(path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    update_categories('web_import_view.xlsx')
```

NB: I also noticed that one of your products contains the same word multiple times (e.g. "ROT HANDLE KEYLOCK ADAPTER W O KEYLOCK"). If you want to count each word only once, you could replace:

```py
product_name_words = [word.lower() for word in product_name.split()]
```

with

```py
product_name_words = set([word.lower() for word in product_name.split()])
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining me the problem and giving very useful recommendations, from which I will learn in the future. 
1) Actually I don't need always to match all words. Can you show me how to match less words for category with more entered words in the dictionary
2) Is there a way to clean all cells in this column except the title, before starting doing program's function, cause of overwriting cannot open excel file normally

PS: I mark your 2nd answer as a best answer!

Thanks in advance! Python is really perfect language to automate the processes which person wants

Comment: I've updated the code to also work with partial matches. The count argument is optional (if you don't specify it, it will search for all words, but if you specify a smaller number it will search for that amount of words). I also cleared the value, so if a category doesn't match, the cell should be cleared now. I didn't have the time to test it yet, so let me know if I broke it ;-)

Comment: Wow, fantastic job! Thank you for helping me! It works wonderful, without mistakes. Keep helping people like that. One day this will reward you. We can close the topic. Have a nice day/night.